# mounting a git http repository using davfs

Tags: apache, svn, git

I'm trying to convert some projects at work from subversion to git. The projects are websites and our current subversion setup uses davfs to mount the repository and point apache's document root there. This way apache in dev runs the code currently checked-into the svn repository.

mount:

```
mount.davfs http://code.repository/svn/site.com /mnt/davfs/site.com
```

httpd.conf:

```
ServerName site.com  
DocumentRoot /mnt/davfs/site.com
```

I'm looking for a way to mimic this setup with git. But, from what I understand, mounting a git repository (yes, our git repo is accessed over http) this way will result in the git repository internals showing up as the docroot and not the code itself.
example:

```
ls /mnt/davfs/gitrepository

Parent Directory
HEAD
branches/
config
description
hooks/
info/
objects/
refs/
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve the desired effect?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Amber and sehe. I could only pick one 'correct' answer, and since Amber's is probably what I'll use, I picked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to browse the *code*, you should be using something like [gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb). If you want to push/pull from the repo, then the internals should be showing up as the docroot.

In a bare repository (the kind that you would use for such a central repo, since you generally don't want to push to non-bare repos), there is no actual checkout of the code files on disk, the only things in that bare repo are the "git internals".

If you want to get a copy of the code on the server out of the repository, you probably want to use `git archive` - possibly in a post-receive hook if you want it to run every time new code is pushed to the repository. See the following man pages for details:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html

http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: I don't actually want either of those. I need the code in the repository to show up as a directory under /mnt/davfs/gitrepository so that I can point apache's document root there and have it see that as if it was any other filesystem. I need it to update when the code changes automatically, as it does with davfs/svn rather than having to cron 'git pull' every minute.

Comment: What you actually need then is a post-receive hook in the server's repository that runs a `git archive` to export the contents of the repository to a directory whenever new code is pushed. See the man page for `git-archive`.

Comment: The problem with that is that the git repository lives on another machine. It's accessible _only_ via http. I can't export the files from the repository to the webserver.

Comment: Then you're kind of stuck. Perhaps you could export the files to a directory on the repository machine, and then mount that separate directory via DAV?

Comment: Perhaps that could work. Something like post-receive hook to export the master branch to another directory and then mount that somehow? Actually, I might be able to get the sysadmins to mount our fileserver on the git repository host, and then i could export the code there and mount that as the docroot.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like it could work. `git archive master | tar -xC /path/to/export/into`

Answer (score 0):

Well the git repo *is* another beast. If you want to browse source code, you need something like gitweb. Mind you, if you just pointed to a svn repo, you'd be looking at internals too; The /mnt/davfs/site.com is probably hosted with apache mod-dav-svn which does something similar as gitweb would do.

You'll want to look at gitweb or competition. Gitweb is IMHO the simplest to setup

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb

For sharing your repository (to make it clonable, e.g.) just serve the tree as static HTTP pages (as docroot directly) because davfs will not (reliably) make it possible for others to push to your repo anyway.

Pushing would be done using the Smart HTTP server, git-daemon or over ssh

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to browse the repository. I need apache to see the code as if they lived on the disk. Let's say I have wordpress in my git repository. I need apache's document root to see the wordpress files and execute them, as wordpress, not to display them to the user.

Comment: @spuriousdata: then you really need to have working tree, not a repo. Cron pull _is_ your best bet, or setup the repo to auto-refresh the working tree after pull: [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_won.27t_I_see_changes_in_the_remote_repo_after_.22git_push.22.3F)

Comment: Ok, so yes, you are correct that the svn repository is running mod_dav_svn, and yes, _that_ webserver displays the files directly with no 'cruft.' So, I see what you're saying about getting gitweb to serve the static http pages, I'm thinking that would probably do what I need. The problem, however, is that I can't install anyting on the git repository server (I work at a HUGE company with LOTS and LOTS of red-tape). Is what you're saying that there is really no other way? Thanks.

Comment: @spuriousdata: My other comment was 6 minutes before your last comment... I suggest you read THAT. (_No, I don't suggest using gitweb at all for this purpose. Even using davfs/mod-dav-svn was (very?!) ill-advised for the same reason._ - you need a working tree that updates. Period. Why complicate things?)

Comment: The answer to your question is: Because I don't make the rules.